# ERROR: Sonar server 'http://localhost:9000' can not be reached in GitLab Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, cicd

I'm trying to integrate SonarQube into my CICD pipeline on GitLab but I am getting an error during the sonarqube stage on Gitlab. I followed the documentation for the [GitLab integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-integration/) so this is how my code looks like:

gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
sonarqube-check:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - sonarqube
```

In the root folder I have the sonar-project.properties file:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=<name>

# --- optional properties ---

# defaults to project key
sonar.projectName=application with SonarQube
# defaults to 'not provided'
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
sonar.sources=src

sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I originally did localhost:9000 for the `sonar.host.url` but that still produces the following error:

```
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://127.0.0.1:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.741s
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/14M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:9000
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:265)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:183)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:115)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263)
    ... 31 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I'm not really sure what to do next for this to work. I also created two environmental variables in GitLab like the documentation says: `SONAR_HOST_URL` and `SONAR_TOKEN` but I'm not sure if that does anything. I set `SONAR_HOST_URL` to localhost:9000 too.... Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated!! I just want to have it so there is a sonarqube check during my CI/CD pipeline in GitLab...

Comment: Please remember that `localhost` (or 127.0.0.1 as it means the same) is the same machine that executes this code. Are you sure you are running SonarQube server on the same machine where your GitLab server/worker resides?

Comment: @raspy I was running the SonarQube server locally, using localhost:9000, but since I want to have a sonarqube check in my Gitlab pipeline for my project, I cannot use localhost (that is correct, right?). If so, then how can I run the SonarQube server?

Comment: You need to run it on a machine that would be available from your pipeline using machine name or IP address, then you would set up your `SONAR_HOST_URL` accordingly, i.e. `http://sonarqube.mydomain.com:9000`.

Comment: Got it! Is there a best way to do this? I was trying to deploy the sonar server by using docker, gitlab ci/cd and Kubernetes but I just ended up getting the same error...